# Angular: Share service between modules with Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 2 different modules that need to share the same data, and keep updating as user make selections.

I'm using `BehaviorSubject` in a service to store the data, but the result i'm getting is this:

each module has it's own 'copy' of the service, each is storing it's own data. so selections made in module 1 exist there, and same for module 2. 
How can I truly share data across all angular app ?

Comment: you need to post code in your questions, otherwise we won't be able to help

Comment: Maybe use a shared module that your 2 current modules imports, and in this module provides the service?

Comment: @hjm I don't think code is relevant here because I don't have any errors or bug or something wrong with the code, it's a matter of knowing how angular works. as for shared module -  tried it, didn't work. same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include your service class name in your root module ( ie AppModule) providers array.

```
@NgModule({ 
 providers: [YourServicee],........

export class AppModule { }
```